# codeigniter system_path and application_folder

Tags: codeigniter

I am running on a bitnami **Linux** server but I am developing on my local **Win7** machine. I am having an issue with setting the `system_path` and `application_folder` on the remote Linux server in **index.php**. I have set

```
$system_path='/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/sub_crud/system';

$application_folder = '/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/sub_crud/application';
```

but a few lines down my code is getting stuck in:

```
// Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. 
    Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, 
    PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }
```

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it means this path "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/sub_crud/system" is not valid. You can try echoing somewhere at the start of `index.php` `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which should give you your correct doc root.

I personally would just do

```
$system = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sub_crud' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'system'
```

Comment: Thx. When I put that line above onto index.php and I look at $system right after the call I see: "C:\xampp\htdocs\sub_crud\system". Could this be a problem with remote debugging in phpStorm? I am using xdebug running on the server.

Comment: nope sounds fine. are you perhaps confused that your remote path and local path is different (it usually...always is)? the above code will work on both systems. `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/sub_crud/system` is a linux hosting path (typically), the one in  your comment is a typical windows  localhost path.